# Is there a way to save the state of a page/DOM and reload it later?

Tags: dart

I am wondering if there's some way restore the state of a page that's executing Dart that doesn't involve manually rebuilding everything (i.e. actively saving objects to local storage, then pulling them and recreating the DOM and action listeners, etc?)

I understand something will have to be stored somewhere but is there a way to easily snapshot and store a state (the entire DOM?), then reload and continue executing code from wherever they were? Like if a user erroneously closes a tab. I'd like them to be able to come back and click "Load" (because I will have stored something in their local storage that knows they were working) and the state is restored.

Answer (score 0):

There might be ways to optimize some things, but in overall, I don't think you will gain much with this strategy. This can even make your code much more complicated if the code needs to behave differently depending on whether your page was loaded and built normally vs loaded from somewhere pre-built.

I suggest to analyze where your application spends the time and processing power and try to optimize specific things with a small focus.

Caching things in the browser that are loaded from the server (usually slow) or results of expensive calculations is quite easy.

Loading HTML with all the event handlers properly attached from localstorage can get quite complicated and might not buy you anything.

Comment: Thank you Günter. I was working on an idea that wasn't going to have "save for later" requirements but seems like that's going to be the best solution to this problem anyway. I appreciate the reply.